# How to disable alignments for block patterns?

Tags: block-editor

I'm creating a block pattern with a cover block as a container and a nested group block with other heading and text blocks inside. I would like to disable the option to change the alignment for all blocks inside the cover. I know with Gutenberg blocks you can disable the option like so:

```
supports: {
    align: [ false ],
},
```

And I thought when registering a block pattern it would look something like this:

```
<!-- wp:group {"supports": {"align": "false"}} -->
```

Is this possible? I can't find any documentation on it.